# sp_executesql not listed in dropdown?

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, ssms

Is anyone aware of why the stored procedure `sp_executesql` doesn't resolve in `SQL Management Studio`'s dropdown list of sp's whereas `sp_sqlexec` does? Is it by design? Is `sp_executesql` set apart from the other stored procedures?

**EDIT:** I mean *resolve* in the editor window / Ctrl-Space kind of way, e.g. after an `EXEC` keyword.
I am aware of where I can find it in the arborescence.

Comment: Even with your edit - extended SPs don't appear in the intellisense either. It's not singled out for special treatment

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking in the Object Explorer, `sp_executesql` doesn't show up under the `System Stored Procedures` node (under `Stored Procedures` in master), but instead under the `System Extended Stored Procedures` node (under `Extended Stored Procedures` in master) - which means that it's actually implemented as compiled code, rather than being implemented in T-SQL.

`sp_sqlexec` is a normal stored procedure, implemented in T-SQL, and so does show up under the `System Stored Prcoedures` node.

If the discussion of nodes, etc above is well wide of the mark, then you need to add more information to your question about *where* you're looking at a "dropdown list of sps".

Comment: I should have been clearer in my question. I know where it is, I mean in the editor window it doesn't resolve after an EXEC keyword, for example

Comment: @WimOmbelets - I just saw your edit and commented to it. It's an extended stored procedure - none of them are shown in Intellisense.

Comment: and now I know that. Thanks.